# getChildFragmentManager() not found in kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

How to use the **`getChildFragmentManager()`** in kotlin fragment class?

I know its very basic question. But no documents found for this.
I searched in google & SO but no results found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val adapterOBJ= YourAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) // val means unmodifiable
```

Comment: not working in my case giving error unresolved reference getChildFragementManager();

Comment: @ArunPrajapati using `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`?

Comment: please add some detail

Answer (score 5):

Just use `childFragmentManager` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`